# The jackal craving for more blood

Tags: past-tense

> Watching all this, the sage thought to himself, "This jackal is a fool as it has become greedy by the smell of blood. If he comes between the fighting rams, it will get rammed and get hurt himself".
>
> No sooner had the sage thought of it, the jackal **craving** for more blood came nearer to the fighting rams, and got caught in the middle of their fight. - Fighting Goats and the Jackal

The story use past tense, So, should't the writer use *was craving*  or *craved*?

Comment: Perhaps if this were an issue tense, yes, but this is actually [a verb phrase as an appositive](http://www.linguisticsgirl.com/nominal-functions-of-english-verbs-and-verb-phrases/), which we construct using present participles (or infinitives in some cases).

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang what exactly is the "appositive phrase"  here, and what noun is it appositive to?

Comment: @Clare, the appositive phrase is "craving for more blood." Correctly punctuated, it should have been comma-ed on both sides. And it's appositive to "the jackal."

Comment: @Shannak. In case you get confused, understand that both Davie's answer below and my answer say the same thing, just from different perspectives.

Comment: @Shannak  *craving* derives its tense from the main verb, which is *came*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, it is most likely a reduced relative clause, and for that (and all of the examples), there should, in my humble opinion, be two commas to segregate it from the rest of the text.

> The Jackal, craving for more blood, came...

Is the same as

> The Jackal, who was craving for more blood, came...

But if you want to know more about Participle clauses, read on. Compare the following sentences:

> Craving for more blood, the Jackal came nearer to the fighting rams

and

> Craving for more blood, the Jackal will come nearer to the fighting rams.

The first sentence is in the past, the second in the future. Both make sense, but the participle clause is the same in each case. That's because its subject, tense, and relationship to the main clause (by way of adverb) are all implied by the main clause. They could easily be re-written with all three. Compare:

> The Jackal was craving for more blood, and so...

and

> The Jackal will be craving for more blood, and so...

Or, if we had a different context

> The Jackal craved...
>
> The Jackal will crave...

It doesn't matter what tense or aspect is implied, whether it's past or present, simple or continuous, the present participle will always have the *-ing* ending.

Also, the subject of the participle clause must be the same as the main clause. So, something like:

> Looking out of the window, the sun set

would be wrong, as it implies that the sun was looking out of the window.

> Looking out of the window, Sally watched the sun set

is perfectly fine because Sally can look out of the window, and Sally can watch the sun set.

There is also a past participle and a perfect participle clause. The same rules apply, but the past participle is used for passive structures:

> **Seen** from a distance, the Taj Mahal looks pure white.

And a perfect participle, which often shows reason or result

**Having had** a huge dinner, I would lie on the porch for an hour.

Comment: Could you please refrain from using `code markup` to highlight sentences?

Comment: Well, I was just trying to go for bold or italic, but that didn't seem to happen. But if you could please refrain from adding 'and' where there was no 'and' before, that would be great.

Comment: Feel free to remove the *ands*. I stuck them there because without them the two sentences share one background.